# Basis for quaternion analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, quaternions

If I have a 3D quaternion function: $$f(x,y,z)=f_0(x,y,z)+f_1(x,y,z)i+f_2(x,y,z)j+f_3(x,y,z)k$$
Where $f_1,f_2,f_3:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and $f(x,y,z)$ is analytic (or more formally left regular in the sense of Fueter), so $\vec{\partial} f(x,y,z)=0$ where:
$$\vec{\partial} := \frac{\partial}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}k$$

For 2D, all analytic functions are polynomials of $(x+iy)$, but in 3D we cannot choose the basis  $q=(ix+jy+kz)$ and have polynomials of $q$. Is there any basis that the quaternions in this form can be expressed as polynomials of? I imagine we will now have two basis functions, $q_1$ and $q_2$, in which all quaternion analytic functions will be polynomials in these two variables.

**Edit:** My physical system is in 3D, so without loss of generality, I am free to return the zeroth parameter and set it to zero at the end. Thus if the new quaternionic variable is $q=u+ix+jy+kz$, I then require $\vec{\partial}f(q)|_{u=0}=0$. And I am looking for a general basis in which all $f(q)$ that follow this analyticity can be represented in a form$^\dagger$:
$$f(q)=\sum_{\alpha}c_{\alpha}\,F(q)^\alpha$$
or (more likely):
$$f(q)=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}c_{\alpha\beta}\,F(q)^\alpha\, G(q)^\beta$$
Where $F,G:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$. For complex mappings, the relation $f(z)=\sum_{\alpha}c_{\alpha}\,F(z)^\alpha$ is satisfied by $F(z)=z$.

$\dagger:$ The indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are indices for the coefficients $c_{\alpha}$ and $c_{\alpha,\beta}$ and are exponentials in $F(q)^\alpha$ and $G(q)^\beta$.

Comment: In complex analysis, $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$. But here your map is $f : \Bbb R^3 \to Q$ where $Q$ is the Quaternions. So the two cases are not really comparable.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, Thanks for the comment, I am setting one component to zero in the end. I've chosen the zeroth component of $q=u+ix+jy+kz$ to set to zero ($u\mapsto0$) to give the 3D restriction needed to match my physical system. I believe I can also set this to zero at the end to maintain the $\partial/\partial u$ term. I'll add an edit now.

Comment: The point is, if you did a similar thing in $\Bbb C$ - i.e., $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ - the concept of analycity is not that of $\Bbb C$, where differentiability is all that is needed, and you have those wonderfully powerful theorems. Instead, you have component-wise real analycity, where even $C^\infty$ is not sufficient to imply it, and instead of a power series (not polynomial) in $x+iy$, you only get power series in $x$. If you want a truly analogous case, you should be looking at maps from $Q \to Q$. It is likely by dropping the real part of the input, you are hobbling the theory.

Comment: You might want to consider expressing $Q = \Bbb C + \Bbb Cj$.